# Present subset of an object with ActiveModel Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, active-model-serializers

I am using ActiveModel Serializers in a Rails project.

The default serializer for the object is fairly large, and nesting an object in API responses result in rather large JSON objects.

Sometimes, I want to embed an object, but only need a small subset of the object's attributes to be present in the JSON.

Obviously, I could do something like this:

`render json: @user, serializer: SmallerUserSerializer`

but that would lead to a lot of duplication.

Is there an option that I can pass to the serializer so that it will only include a subset of the serializers attributes? Eg:

`class BlogSerializer
  # This is pseudocode. Does not actually work.
  has_one :user, only_show: [:user_id, :profile_url]
end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method and call `to_json` on the user object. Then add that method name to your list of attributes. The method can be called user also.

```
class BlogSerializer
  attributes :id, :user

  def user
    object.user.to_json( only: [ :id, :profile_url ] )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [active model serialzers gem](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers).

Your pseudo code will become the following simple modularized code:

```
class BlogSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :user_id, :profile_url
end
```

Guide: http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers

Answer (score 0):

Create a method and call to_json on the user object. Then add that method name to your list of attributes. The method can be called user also.

```
class BlogSerializer
  require 'json'
  attributes :id, :user

  def user
    JSON.parse "#{object.user.to_json( only: [ :id, :profile_url ] )}"
  end
end
```